# How to determine the data type of incoming socket data in python while keeping the socket open

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, struct, tcp

I can't seem to find the problem. What I want to do is, keep the client and server socket open while differentiating the type of incoming data using structs. The socket connection seems to break after I run both server and client code. Maybe there is something to do with the while loops inside server code. Please help.

Here's my server code:

```
                import struct
                import socket
                import threading
                import random

                # Define the server's IP address and port
                SERVER_IP = '0.0.0.0'
                SERVER_PORT = 55555

                # Create a socket for the server
                server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
                server_socket.listen()

                # Dictionary to store client sockets based on their public keys
                client_sockets = {}

                def handle_client(client_socket):
                    try:
                        while True:
                            # Receive a message
                            message_type, received_message = receive_message(client_socket)
                            
                            if message_type == 1:
                                # Store the client socket in the dictionary with the public key as the key
                                client_sockets[received_message] = client_socket
                                print(f"Client connected with public key: {received_message}")

                            if message_type == 2:
                                # Example: Sending a broadcast message to all connected clients
                                print(received_message)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error handling client: {e}")
                    

                def receive_message(socket):
                    # Receive the header
                    print("Received message")
                    header = socket.recv(8)

                    # Unpack the message type and length
                    message_type, length = struct.unpack('!II', header)

                    # Receive the message data
                    message_data = socket.recv(length)

                    if message_type == 2:
                        # Extract regular message and public key as bytes
                        null_char_index = message_data.index(b'\0')
                        regular_message = message_data[:null_char_index].decode('utf-8')
                        public_key = message_data[null_char_index+1:] if len(message_data) > null_char_index+1 else None
                        return message_type, regular_message, public_key
                    
                    else:
                        # Handle other message types as needed
                        return message_type, message_data

                def send_message(socket, message_type, message_data):
                    # Pack the message type and length
                    header = struct.pack('!II', message_type, len(message_data))

                    # Send the header
                    socket.sendall(header)

                    # Send the message data
                    socket.sendall(message_data)


                while True:
                    # Accept a client connection
                    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

                    # Create a new thread to handle the client
                    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
                    client_thread.start()
```

Here's my client side code:

```
                import socket
                import struct 
                import threading
                from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
                from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
                from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import x25519, ed25519
                from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
                from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
                from os import urandom



                def generate_key_pair():
                    private_key = x25519.X25519PrivateKey.generate()
                    public_key = private_key.public_key()
                    return private_key, public_key


                def send_message(socket, message_type, message_data, public_key=None):
                    # Pack the message type and length
                    header = struct.pack('!II', message_type, len(message_data) + len(public_key) + 1 if public_key else len(message_data))
                

                    # Send the message data
                    if message_type == 1:
                        socket.sendall(header)
                        # If it's a public key, send as-is (assuming it's already in bytes)
                        socket.sendall(message_data)
                    elif message_type == 2:
                        socket.sendall(header)
                        # If it's a regular message with a public key, concatenate both with a null character separator before sending
                        if public_key:
                            combined_data = message_data.encode('utf-8') + b'\0' + public_key
                            print(combined_data)
                        else:
                            # If no public key, send only the regular message
                            socket.sendall(message_data.encode('utf-8'))
                    else:
                        # Handle other message types as needed
                        print("Unsupported message type:", message_type)

                def receive_messages(socket):
                    while True:
                        try:
                            # Receive messages from the server
                            message_type, received_message = receive_message(socket)

                            if message_type == 2:
                                # If it's a regular message, print it
                                print("Received message from server:", received_message.decode('utf-8'))

                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Error receiving message from server: {e}")
                            break

                def receive_message(socket):
                    # Receive the header
                    header = socket.recv(8)

                    # Unpack the message type and length
                    message_type, length = struct.unpack('!II', header)

                    # Receive the message data
                    message_data = socket.recv(length)

                    return message_type, message_data

                # Create a client socket
                client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                client_socket.connect(('44.216.25.151', 55555))

                # Generate client key pair
                private_key, public_key = generate_key_pair()

                # Serialize public key to bytes
                serialized_pub_key = public_key.public_bytes(
                    encoding=serialization.Encoding.Raw,
                    format=serialization.PublicFormat.Raw
                )

                # Send the public key to the server
                send_message(client_socket, 1, serialized_pub_key)

                # Start a thread to receive messages from the server
                receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(client_socket,))
                receive_thread.start()


                while True:
                    # Get user input or any other data to send
                    user_input = input("Enter a message to send: ")
                    # Sending a regular message
                    regular_message = user_input
                    send_message(client_socket, 2, regular_message, serialized_pub_key)
```

The output of client side code is:

```
                $ python3 client3.py 
                Enter a message to send: hi
                b'hi\x00:{uF\xac\xf6\\m\x8a\xb5\xb2\x14\xdeuq\xa5{\\-\xd0W\x1e,C\xf0\xfa\xa4\x87{#\xfa\x1f'
                Enter a message to send: hi
                b'hi\x00:{uF\xac\xf6\\m\x8a\xb5\xb2\x14\xdeuq\xa5{\\-\xd0W\x1e,C\xf0\xfa\xa4\x87{#\xfa\x1f'
                Enter a message to send:
```

And the output of server side is:

```
                $ python3 server7.py
                Received message
                Client connected with public key: b':{uF\xac\xf6\\m\x8a\xb5\xb2\x14\xdeuq\xa5{\\-\xd0W\x1e,C\xf0\xfa\xa4\x87{#\xfa\x1f'
                Received message
                Error handling client: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Do not assume a `recv(n)` will receive exactly n bytes. It can return 1-n bytes or zero if the socket is closed. Buffer receives and extract complete messages, or wrap the socket in a file-like object via `socket.makefile` to do the buffering for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your server-side code is handling incoming messages of type 2 (regular message with public key). Now the error that you're getting "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" is basically saying to you that the `receive_message` function on the server-side is returning more values than expected by the `handle_client` function.

There are actually two problems in your code, **Mismatch in `receive_message` - primarily the problem is within returned values**. And **sending messages in client itself**. I already explained what happens when it comes to mismatch in `receive_message` function, now to elaborate the second one: When delivering a type 2 message, the client's `send_message` function only sends the header and the combined data when `public_key` is available. On the other hand, if `public_key` is None, the function does not deliver the combined data.

Solving this would have first to go from solving/modifying Server Code, which will involve:

1. Standardization of a `receive_message` function's Return Values: The amount of values you return must always be the same. `Message_type`, `message_data`, and `public_key`, for example, are the three values that it can always return (which can be `None` if not applicable).
2. Update of a handle_client function: You need to update the `handle_client` function to handle the additional return value from `receive_message`.

The second part of solving your problem is modifying Client Code:
Correcting `send_message` logic in a way that you will make sure that, whether or not public_key is present, the message data is transmitted after the header.

Your code should be looking something like this:

**Server Code updating:**

```
def receive_message(socket):
    # Code before    
    message_data = socket.recv(length)
    public_key = None
    if message_type == 2:
        return message_type, regular_message, public_key
    else:
        return message_type, message_data, public_key
```

In `handle_client` function:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):
    try:
        while True:
            message_type, received_message, public_key = receive_message(client_socket)
```

**Client Code Updating:**
In `send_message` function:

```
def send_message(socket, message_type, message_data, public_key=None):
    # Existing code

    socket.sendall(header)

    # Revised logic to send message data
    if message_type == 1:
        socket.sendall(message_data)
    elif message_type == 2:
        combined_data = message_data.encode('utf-8') + b'\0' + public_key if public_key else message_data.encode('utf-8')
        socket.sendall(combined_data)
    else:
        # Handle other message types as needed
        print("Unsupported message type:", message_type)
```

I hope this will put you on the right path.

Comment: Yes. It worked. I've just forgotten to add socket.sendall(combined_data) in client side code and also worked when I return the correct values.Thanks